# How to check for isomorphism of two graphs using adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Is there any way to check for the isomorphism of two graphs using the adjacency matrix in a simple way?

If it is, then please let me know...

Comment: The simple way is to compare every permutation of rows/columns of one matrix to the other matrix and see if they are the same. This is also the long way.

Answer (score 3):

No polynomial-time algorithm is known for this problem, though many instances can be solved quickly in practice using a tool like [nauty](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ealgorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

If they are isomorph only the labeling is different.

So sorting the rows of the matrix (and accordingly reorder he columns also(if you swap rows, you also need to swap the columns)) should lead to two exact equal matrices, if the graphs are isomorph.

---

If you compare a lot of not isomorph graphs, you should make some quick-checks first. Like:

- they need to have the same number of entries in both matrices
- same number of rows for the same number of entries in both matrices

This way you can fail early (much cheaper than the sorting)

Comment: Suppose you compare two rows i and j lexicographically, and consequently decide to swap them, as well as their corresponding columns. Swapping the columns could cause a separate pair of rows p, q that were previously correctly ordered to become incorrectly ordered, so it's not clear that the sorting process would ever terminate.

Comment: This problem goes away if you use an ordering predicate that isn't affected by column swaps, such as ordering by the sum of all entries in the row, but if there is more than one row with the same sum, this predicate cannot totally order the rows.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Can you provide a proper algorithm for this?